# Delete duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

A confusion and duplication of questions is generated when looking for answers to questions about the **Open source Software** on the forum.
This question is to admin to ask him deletion of duplicate question:

**1- Delete the actual question in the link below**

[Delete duplicate questions](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7568/delete-duplicate-questions)

**2-  Delete all the question in the link below :**
[How license OpenSource Software?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/how-license-opensource-software)

**3- Delete the Highlighted part of the question in the link below:**

[Practical steps to licence Free software and Open Source Projects](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/practical-steps-to-licence-free-software-and-open-source-projects)

the Highlighted part is shown in the following figure
[image]

Comment: I think you want me to delete this question and [How license OpenSource Software?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7512). However, I'm not totally sure, so I want to confirm before I do that. However, you might need to ask: you can delete your own questions if they have no answers, using the `delete` link below the question body. (You can that for both [How license OpenSource Software?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7512) and this question itself, if that's what you wanted to do.) For item #3, the red-colored posted *are* deleted; only you can see them.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but I'll take a shot.

In general, we don't delete questions that have been marked as a duplicate because they serve as signposts to the answer - this is especially important for search results, as the duplicate might use different keywords and therefore show up in a wider range of searches. Deleting the duplicate would lose that ability. This also applies to *migrated* questions that have been moved from one site to another, as they also serve as a record of what happened to the post - the migration "stub" will be automatically removed after a period of time when it's deemed to have run its course of usefulness.

With that in mind:

**1. Delete "[Delete duplicate questions](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7568/delete-duplicate-questions)"**
That link goes to this post on the main Open Source site, where you originally posted it. It has since been migrated to here - the question I'm answering. The link here goes to the migration stub, which we don't generally delete for the reasons above.

**2. Delete "[How license OpenSource Software?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/how-license-opensource-software)"**
This question has been marked as a duplicate. Again, those aren't generally deleted for the reasons above.

**3. Delete the highlighted part of "[Practical steps to licence Free software and Open Source Projects](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/practical-steps-to-licence-free-software-and-open-source-projects)"**
I'm not sure what you mean by highlighted here. If you mean the part of the page with a red background, that red background means the post has been deleted - so, if that's your meaning, no further action is necessary here since it's already been deleted.